# Unable to download the exported files

Tags: export, importexport, database-export

When I try to download the export file following errors throw up:

The webpage at https://example.com/example_admin/admin/export_file/download/key/e96e56437082201cf67598aa719e389dd43e9c11649fd63df8cd0bb0adaccfcd/?filename=stock_sources_20210620_070435.csv might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

And when you give the export folder access using this command you can then download the file:
sudo chmod -R 777 export

We are using Magento 2.3.6 and Alicloud Server with ngnix.

Which access should be given to the php user so that exported files are automatically available.

Answer (score 0):

this would happen because whenever a file is created, it changes the default owner and group of the file and permissions, try to login to your root user from console and set the default owner and group to **root www-data**.